# The “wc -l” command shows zero lines

Tags: linux, file

I input "wc -l myFile" command, the shell show "0 myFile",but the file has a lot of characters,("wc -c myFile" is 1000000000+) and maybe it has only one line.
So why it happends??!
  Thanks!

Comment: *"maybe it has only one line"* Probably, why not check?

Comment: Can't you check? Too big to notice? `egrep '^.*$' | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

That means there is no "new line" character in the file

Comment: That is true, but where is the text written then ?
it is written on first line of file , then why wc -l shows zero ?